# If row in datagrid is clicked then open new window

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am making an WPF application. I have a datagrid with static items in it. For now I want to show a new window when clicked on a row.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my second Window I want to open when clicked: `WindowMail.cs`

```
using System;

namespace Phish_Finder
{
    internal class WindowMail
    {
        internal void Show()
        {
            WindowMail wm = new WindowMail();
            wm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method in my first window `Mainwindow.xaml.cs`

```
   private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentRowIndex = URLGRID.Items.IndexOf(URLGRID.CurrentItem);
        {
            if (URLGRID.CurrentItem != null)
            {
                WindowMail wm = new WindowMail();
                wm.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my datagrid

```
DataGrid x:Name="URLGRID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400"
Margin="60,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1350" Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded" 
MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick"
```

I am new to WPF and I think that I am mixing up where I should put methods. But I am not sure.

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: You call the show function inside your show function, looks like an infinite loop to me

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the code

```
internal class WindowMail
{
    internal void Show()
    {
        WindowMail wm = new WindowMail();
        wm.Show();
    }
}
```

needs a little change. I here believe that the class WindowMail is actually the cs class after the WindowMail.xaml file.

Here you need to change the

```
        WindowMail wm = new WindowMail();
        wm.Show();
```

lines into

```
this.Show(); //Standard function of a window
```

else your code keeps on repeating Infinite loop...

Also, things you need to change: I believe the function Show already exists on the window level. So rename it like below or do an override of the function.

```
public void OpenDialog(bool asDialog)
{
    if(asDialog)
        this.ShowDialog();
    else
        this.Show();
}
```

Then, for calling your function:

```
private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
   if (URLGRID.SelectedItem!= null)
   {
       WindowMail wm = new WindowMail();
       wm.OpenDialog(true);
   }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var currentRowIndex = URLGRID.Items.IndexOf(URLGRID.selectedItem);
    {
        if (URLGRID.selectedItem != null)
        {
            WindowMail wm = new WindowMail();
            wm.Show();
        }

    }
}
```